# can not patch HTS-2.3 for HTK-3.4.1

Tags: text-to-speech, htk, hts

I cannot patch HTS-2.3_for_HTK-3.4.1.patch at ubuntu 16.04.
Does anyone have an idea to resolve it?

```html
~/hts-htk/htk$ ls
AUTHORS       config.status  env       HTK       HTKTools                     Makefile
ChangeLog     config.sub     FAQ       HTKBook   HTS-2.3_for_HTK-3.4.1.patch  Makefile.in
config.guess  configure      HLMLib    HTKLib    install-sh                   README
config.log    configure.ac   HLMTools  HTKLVRec  LICENSE


$ patch -p1 -d . < HTS-2.3_for_HTK-3.4.1.patch
can't find file to patch at input line 4
Perhaps you used the wrong -p or --strip option?
The text leading up to this was:
--------------------------
|diff -pbBEwurNa '--ignore-matching-lines=.*vc_id.*' HTK-3.4.1/HTKLVRec/HDecode.c HTS-2.3_for_HTK-3.4.1/HTKLVRec/HDecode.c
|--- HTK-3.4.1/HTKLVRec/HDecode.c   2009-03-13 03:55:15.000000000 +0900
|+++ HTS-2.3_for_HTK-3.4.1/HTKLVRec/HDecode.c   2015-12-21 11:02:23.000000000 +0900
--------------------------
File to patch:
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/thmoe.jpg

Comment: HDecode.c has to be downloaded and unpacked separately. Maybe you missed it.

Comment: oh, thank you. I found my misstake.
I download HTS-2.3_for_HTK-3.4.1 and HDecode-3.5.beta-1
It is not good, I have to download HDecode-3.4.1